# How do I get elements on different size lists inside another list?

Tags: python

How do I get all elements inside of different sizes sublists?

I have sublists inside of a_list:

```
a_list = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]
```

I need to group all elements according to their indexes and I need it to ignore if a sublist is missing an element.

This is the output I need:

```
['a', 'a', 'a']
['b', 'b'] # here's where I'm having problems
```

I have tried:

```
for index, a in enumerate(a_list):
   another_list = (list(zip(*a_list))[index]) # IndexError
```

Also tried:

```
another_list = list()
for index, a in enumerate(a_list):      
  another_list.append([x[index] for x in a_list])  # IndexError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
a_list = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]

r = len(max(a_list, key=len))
z = [sum([x[i:i+1] for x in a_list], []) for i in range(r)]
z
>>> [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]
```

---

**Explanation:**

Let's consider your second attempt:

```
another_list = list()
for index, a in enumerate(a_list):      
  another_list.append([x[index] for x in a_list])  # IndexError
```

The problem with this code is:

1. you are iterating over `a_list`, while you should iterate over indexes (I use the range of the longest sublist)
2. you get IndexError because you access the sublist element by `x[index]`, while I use `x[index:index+1]`, which returns a list instead (an empty one if index is out of range)
3. I use `sum(index_group, [])` in order to flatten the group (see code below)

In my code I then merged all this in a list comprehension, but below can find an equivalent version using a `for` loop as you did.

**Modified version of your code:**

```
a_list = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]
another_list = list()
for index in range(max([len(x) for x in a_list])):  # loop over indexes
    # create a list of sublist slices containing the index-th element
    ind_group = [x[index:index+1] for x in a_list]
    # flatten the list
    flat_ind_group = sum(ind_group, [])
    another_list.append(flat_ind_group)
another_list

>>> [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]
```

Comment: This worked! Would you mind explaining your thought on this?

Comment: Updated with an explanation

Answer (score 2):

You need [**`zip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue` handling the empty case + a [**`chain.from_iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) for flattening lists.

```
[list(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in zip_longest(*a_list, fillvalue='')]
```

**Code**:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

a_list = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]

print([list(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in zip_longest(*a_list, fillvalue='')])
# [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first flatten your list and then use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module to count the frequencies

```
from collections import Counter

a_list = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]
a_list_flat = [i for sub in a_list for i in sub]

another_list = [[k for _ in range(v)] for k, v in Counter(a_list_flat).items()]
# [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]
```

Alternatively,

```
another_list = [[k]*v for k, v in Counter(a_list_flat).items()]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work if the elements inside of the sublist are different. Another words, if a_list is [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e']] , another_list will be [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e']] instead of ['a', 'c', 'e']. Maybe the question was not very clear but I'm trying to group by the index on the sublist.

Comment: @supertramp: Why would in that case, anothr_list will be ['a', 'c', 'e']? What happens to b and d?

Comment: b and d would be on the second sublist. E.g. [['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd']]  Just think about a_list with different chars for each sublist.